# Alignment the text in corechart using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I am using corechart. When the pie chart appears, want to print the details of pie chart below the chart.

**Example** :
Want to print the details of chart in given form.
(color red) reading : 20% , (color blue) sleeping :30% , (color green) Playing :10%
and so on...

[image: Pie Chart]

Could anyone please help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function drawVisualization() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Investment');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
                    data.addRows(5);
                    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Cash');
                    data.setValue(0, 1, 21217.31);
                    data.setValue(1, 0, 'GIC 9658');
                    data.setValue(1, 1, 2500.30);
                    data.setValue(2, 0, 'GIC 9657');
                    data.setValue(2, 1, 1515.18);
                    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Fund 5612');
                    data.setValue(3, 1, 5115.74);
                    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Fund 5617');
                    data.setValue(4, 1, 3032.33);                                                                                                               

        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '$'});
        formatter.format(data, 1);

        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(data, {
                    title: 'Distribution of Assets', 
                    legend: {
            position: 'left',
            alignment:'end'
                },
                is3D: true, 
                pieSliceText: 'value', 
                pieSliceTextStyle:{color: '#FFFFFF', fontName: 'Sans-Serif', fontSize: 14}, 
                legendTextStyle: {color: '#333333', fontName: 'Sans-Serif', fontSize: 14}, 
                tooltipTextStyle: {color: '#666666', fontName: 'Sans-Serif', fontSize: 14},
                chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%"}
                    });
                }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

            </script>
```